# Change DisplayNameFor (name) using WCF and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I'm running a project with a WCF-service and a MVC-client. I'd like to display proper columnnames when populating the data within the MVC view. As per default, the view is generated using `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeeAmount)` - this displayed: "FeeAmount" on my View. I'd like to change this to something proper.

Using the `DisplayName`-attribute dosen't work on client. Here is my DataContract:

```
[Required]
[DataMember]
[DisplayName("Fee")]
public decimal FeeAmount { get; set; }
```

Using the `DataMember(name = "Fee")` changes the propertyname. I'd like to keep the propertyname "FeeAmount", and only change how it's being displayed.

How can I achieve this, the easiest way?

I'm using EF code first, WCF and MVC.

Comment: are you using attribute Display name for the view model or the entity name?

Comment: If dont understand you saying Using Displayname attribute seems restricted.

Comment: @JinsPeter sorry about that. Please check my updated question - hope it's better, otherwise let me know.

Comment: Please check if my answer is working. I usually do this and it works for me

Comment: Do you have a separate shared assembly for your model or do you use generated one on the client?

Comment: @Unicco did my answer work for you?

Comment: You can easily make labels also, it is not nessesarry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
use a `[Display(Name ="fee")]` attribute at your viewmodel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Fee")]
public decimal FeeAmount{get;set;}
```

and use `@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.FeeAmount)` in cshtml